one one correspondence between vector bundle and locally free sheaf over connected manifold
I am following R O wells's Differential analysis on complex manifolds link(https://thunv.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/graduate-texts-in-mathematics-65-r-o-wells-jr-auth-differential-analysis-on-complex-manifolds-springer-new-york-1980.pdf)   where on page 40 he states a following theorem:
**Theorem 1.13 : **Let $X=(X,S)$ be a connected $S-manifold$. Then there is a one one correspondence between(isomorphism classes of ) $S-bundles$ over $X$ and (isomorphism classes of ) locally free shaeves of $S-modules$ over X.
where $S$ denote the structure on a manifold it can be smooth or  complex or real analytic.
one side corespondence is clear i.e given a vector bundle we have a sheaf of sections which turns out to be localy free sheaves. For the other part assuming say $L$ be a locally free sheaves of $S-modules$. Then we can find an open covering $\lbrace U_{\alpha}\rbrace$ of X such that there is an isomorphism $g_{\alpha}: L(U_{\alpha})\rightarrow S(U{\alpha})^r$ for some $r>0$. Then in the proof its mentioned that r does not depend on $\alpha$, since $X$ is connected.
this is not clear to me: why $r$ doesnot  depend on $\alpha$ if $X$ connected manifold? I mean what is the argument behind it?
Second questions is how to verify that isomorphism classes are preserved under this correspondence?

Without getting bogged down in notation, the value of $r$ which "works over $U_\alpha$" (let's call this the rank of $L$ over $U_\alpha$) has to be the same for any pair of indices such that $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \ne \varnothing$ (set up the obvious commutative square relating $g_\alpha$ and $g_\beta$ to the restriction maps). Any two points on a connected manifold are joined by a chain of overlapping chart nbds, so we see that the rank is constant over a connected manifold (and of course connectedness is necessary because opens contained in distinct connected components never intersect).
